# Map to non managed entity with criteria-api

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

In JPA1 you could map a result to a non-managed entity by something like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.test.TestInfo(e.name, e.city) from Example e");
```

In JPA2 you could do it like this :

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(“SELECT e.name, e.city from Example e”,TestInfo.Class);
```

How would I do that with the criteria-api? I simply don't know the buzzwords to google for.

Any hints?

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done via [CriteriaBuilder.construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...%29). First argument is class of result, following arguments are [Selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Selection.html)s.